# Unity - вызвать метод в игре в заданную дату

Tags: c#, unity3d

игра на `Android`, допустим есть некий метод, его необходимо привести в действие начиная с определенной даты, допустим сегодня `02.02.2018`, метод не работает в игре, а начиная с `05.02.2018` метод будет выполняться когда игрок зайдет в игру, очень прошу объяснить как и какими способами это возможно реализовать.

Comment: способов много. можно в начало метода проверку даты вставить и прерывать его выполнение если дата не подходит. Можно встроить планировщик в приложение и переложить на него выполнение некоторых действий по календарю событий. В общем варианты есть, но надо понимать для чего это нужно, чтобы что-то конкретное советовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В C# существует структура [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx), которая отвечает за дату и время. У этой структуры есть метод DateTime.TryParse(string, out DateTime), который пытается превратить переданную строчку в экземпляр DateTime, и поле DateTime.Now - возвращающее текущее значение даты и времени. Примеры применения есть внизу статьи msdn, на которую я дал ссылку.

Т.е. последовательность действий примерно такая:
- Записываете где-нибудь у себя в настройках дату и время в международном стандарте (тоже есть в статье) в виде строки.
- При вызове метода превращаете эту строку в структуру DateTime с помощью TryParse.
- Сравниваете текущее значение, полученное из DateTime.Now с вашим и либо выполняете метод, либо нет.
Однако, стоит помнить, что такую проверку можно обойти просто сменив время на устройстве. Как вариант - получать время из интернета сторонними способами (если вы используете какие-нибудь плагины от интернет сервисов, например, рекламы, там вполне может присутствовать подобная возможность), а если интернет недоступен - метод тоже не доступен.